# Excel 2013 PowerPivot with Timeline

Tags: excel-formula, powerpivot

Creating a pivot table that is based on a timeline. Is there any way to get the begin date and end date that is currently being referenced by the slider?

Comment: by "get" you mean to use it in custom field calculations?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is show the dates relating to the current 'filter context' then you can simply use:

```
Beginning: =MIN(Table[Date])
End:       =MAX(Table[Date])
```

If you want to do something more complex then you will need to expand your question.

Jacob